# Is it possible to override only some arguments of a Symfony 4 service without compiler passes?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'd like to override a service definition coming from a third-party bundle, which looks like this:

```
# vendor/some_vendor/some_bundle/src/Resources/config/config.yml
services:
    SomeBundle\Service\ServiceClass:
        arguments:
            $arg1:
                - 'abcd'
                - 'efgh'
            $arg2:
                - '1234'
                - '5678'
```

```
namespace SomeBundle\Service;
class ServiceClass 
{
    public function __construct(array $arg1 = [], array $arg2 = [], array $arg3 = []) 
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

I'd like to override the config in my app/config/config.yml adding $arg3 argument,
but keeping the existing ones, $arg1 and $arg2.

When I do like this

```
# app/config/config.yml
# $arg1 and $arg2 config values are lost
services:
    SomeBundle\Service\ServiceClass:
        arguments:
            $arg3:
                - 'uvw'
                - 'xyz'
```

$arg1 and $arg2 values are lost. So I have to copy the full set of original config values
from the third-party bundle and then add my additional config for $arg3:

```
# app/config/config.yml
# This, of course, works fine, but I'd like to avoid copying $arg1 and $arg2
services:
    SomeBundle\Service\ServiceClass:
        arguments:
            $arg1:
                - 'abcd'
                - 'efgh'
            $arg2:
                - '1234'
                - '5678'
            $arg3:
                - 'uvw'
                - 'xyz'
```

So the question is, is it possible somehow to add or replace some arguments and keep values of other ones, just by overriding service in my config.yml, without doing complicated things like writing a compiler pass class

Comment: I'm not aware of any built in method besides compiler passes that can accomplish this.  But while creating a pass may seem formidable, like many things it's not so bad once you have done it.  You basically just need to grab the bundle's service definition and add an argument to it.  Give it a try and if you have trouble then update your question.  Passes are a good tool to have.

Comment: @Cerad thank you for your answer! I don't have much troubles with writing compiler passes, I just thought that doing this through yml config is a bit clear/illustrative/human readable way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But only if the third party bundle sets the arguments as parameters, then you can override them.

Comment: I didn't downwote, but is this really an answer? :) If you do know a way to do this, please share